# Subquery with nested if else condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, nested, subquery, tableau-desktop

I have the following 3 calculated columns which define the training status for each employee:

1. training status in 2023 calculated as if [test attribute] = 'e1' and year([assigned date]) = 2023 then 'overdue' elseif [test attribute] = 'e2' and year([assigned date]) = 2023 then 'late completion' else '' end;
2. training status in 2022 calculated as if [test attribute] = 'e1' and year([assigned date]) = 2022 then 'overdue' ;
3. training status in 2021 calculated as if [test attribute] = 'e1' and year([assigned date]) = 2021 then 'overdue';

I want to get the exceptions count where if training status in 2023 = e1 or e2 then that population and if training status for 2021 or training status for 2022 = e1 then from those ids.

In the sample data below, the exceptions count should be 3 (Henry, Sam and Tom). We don't count Mike because his training status in 2023 is neither e1 nor e2.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  test attribute VARCHAR(255),
  assigned_date DATE,
  type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO users
(id,    name,    test attribute, assigned_date, type ) VALUES
(102,   'Henry', 'E1',           '2023-05-01',  'comp'),
(102,   'Henry', 'E1',           '2022-01-30',  'comp'),
(102,   'Henry', 'E2',           '2023-05-01',  'comp'),
(101,   'Mike',  'X',            '2023-10-21',  'other'),
(101,   'Mike',  'E1',           '2022-06-19',  'other'),
(100,   'Sam',   'E2',           '2023-11-12',  'comp'),
(100,   'Sam',   'E1',           '2021-09-18',  'other'),
(100,   'Sam',   'E1',           '2023-11-12',  'other'),
(103,   'Tom',   'X',            '2023-11-12',  'other'),
(103,   'Tom',   'E1',           '2021-09-18',  'comp'),
(103,   'Tom',   'E2',           '2023-11-12',  'other');

SELECT * FROM users;
```

I tried the following calculations but it is not giving me accurate count. I have a calculated field called exceptions count in Tableau, where I am trying to get the count and this is what I have tried:

```
If ([test attribute] IN ('e1', 'e2') and year([assigned date]) = 2023) and if [test attribute] = 'e1' and year([assigned date]) IN (2022, 2021) then 1  else 0 end;
```

What is wrong?

Comment: You can't create a column with a space in the name (`test attribute VARCHAR(255),`) so you clearly still haven't tested it.

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression where you don't get what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]--then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Comment: This post is unclear. I have partly clarified. Please edit. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Avoid social & meta commentary. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values. [SQL query from a human-readable description](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33952141/3404097) PS Please indent code reasonably. Please don't repeat what code says in prose. Say why it was written in application terms when not obvious.

Comment: (1) The second `and` in your posted "if" expression seems suspicious. Should that be an `or`? (2) You may be able to use *conditional aggregation* to count the exceptional conditions - something like `COUNT(CASE WHEN <condition> THEN 1 END) AS ExceptionCount` or `COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN <condition> THEN id END) AS ExceptionCount`.

Comment: Why did you remove all that content? If you are isolating to the If OK but leave the initialization part of the [mre] for it & any other useful parts. Although you should minimize the data. Don't edit in a way that invalidates reasonable posted answers. Pin down the problem in your query, show what the subexpressions are calculating, for a minimal reproducible example. You need to say what you expected & why. I rolled back your edit but changed the question about your goal to a statement. Again: Find the 1st problem with your expression & ask about what you don't understand. Not your goal.

Comment: @User277883 how did you get on?

Answer (score 0):

SQL uses "case expressions" instead of if/else syntax (although you can use if/else in T-SQL) but the syntax of a case expression is something you should probably get used to if using SQL. The syntax is very similar to your stated requirement, e.g:

```
select
      case
        when [training category] = 'E1' and assigned_year = 2023 then 'overdue' 
        when [training category] = 'E2' and assigned_year = 2023 then 'late completion' 
        else '' 
      end as calc1
    , case
        when [training category] = 'E1' and assigned_year < 2023 then 'overdue' 
      end as calc2
   , *
from myusers
outer apply (select year(try_cast([assigned date] as date)) as assigned_year) oa1
```

see this working [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/529d6/1)

| calc1 | calc2 | id | name | training category | assigned date | type | assigned_year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| overdue |  | 102 | Henry | E1 | 2023-05-01 | comp | 2023 |
|  | overdue | 102 | Henry | E1 | 2022-01-30 | comp | 2022 |
| late completion |  | 102 | Henry | E2 | 2023-05-01 | comp | 2023 |
|  |  | 101 | Mike | X | 2023-10-21 | other | 2023 |
|  | overdue | 101 | Mike | E1 | 2022-06-19 | other | 2022 |
| late completion |  | 100 | Sam | E2 | 2023-11-12 | comp | 2023 |
|  | overdue | 100 | Sam | E1 | 2021-09-18 | other | 2021 |
| overdue |  | 100 | Sam | E1 | 2023-11-12 | other | 2023 |
|  |  | 103 | Tom | X | 2023-11-12 | other | 2023 |
|  | overdue | 104 | Tom | E1 | 2021-09-18 | comp | 2021 |
| late completion |  | 103 | Tom | E2 | 2023-11-12 | other | 2023 |

In your sample data you show the "assigned date" as a varchar, so I have included a way to cast that to a date. If the date is already a date column then the `try_cast([assigned ddate] as date)` isn't required.

Note: A case expression starts "top to bottom" so if the first "when" is true it ignores any following "when" or "else" conditions, if the first is false then it evaluates the next "when", and so on until finished (so it doesn't need "elseif" but can achieve the equivalent).

Small point: Whilst the correct term is "**case expression**" you will regrettably find many references to "case statement".

```
==================================================================================
```

I think you may be able to combine "calc1" and "calc2" by using "less than or equal" for the overdue conditions:

```
select
      case
        when [training category] = 'E1' and assigned_year <= 2023 then 'overdue' 
        when [training category] = 'E2' and assigned_year = 2023 then 'late completion' 
        else null 
      end as calc1
   , *
from myusers
outer apply (select year(try_cast([assigned date] as date)) as assigned_year) oa1
```

Comment: sorry I took an easy path in the second case expression to use "less than 2023" but I feel you are able to correct this as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i am not trying to get count of different conditions.  I have a calculated field in tableau, where i want to get the count of exception based on the condition defined in the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a sub-query (CTE in my example) to calculate the error conditions then filter by them. And then use `count(distinct id)` to get the count.

```
with cte as (
    select id, [Name]
      , case when exists (select 1 from users c2 where c2.id = c1.id and year(assigned_date) = 2023 and training_category in ('E1','E2')) then 1 else 0 end Has2023Exception
      , case when exists (select 1 from users c2 where c2.id = c1.id and year(assigned_date) in (2021, 2022) and training_category in ('E1')) then 1 else 0 end Has2022or2021Exception
    from users c1
)
select count(distinct id)
from cte
where Has2023Exception = 1 and Has2022or2021Exception = 1;
```

Returns

| Count |
| --- |
| 3 |

Or you could use the `having` clause to filter the rows, then count them e.g.

```
with cte as (
    select 1 Num
    from users
    group by id, [Name]
    having max(case when year(assigned_date) = 2023 and training_category in ('E1','E2') then 1 else 0 end) = 1
        and max(case when year(assigned_date) in (2021, 2022) and training_category in ('E1') then 1 else 0 end) = 1
)
select count(*)
from cte;
```

Which might not be much smaller or simpler, but performs better due to only a single access of the table.